# Understand function from get set method

Tags: c#, get, set

I am using a get set method to loop another method. As shown below, I am trying to increase the value of Table10_3 in the ValuesForTableLooping class. In the Main method, I have called  the get set property to increase the value by one.

I have 2 questions at hand,

1. Is there a way to call the get set method without putting it as `Inc.Val = 0;`?
2. Why does changing any value in `Inc.Val = 0;` not affect the outcome?

```
class Class2
{
    public class ValuesForTableLooping
    {
        public static int Table10_3 = 1;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3);

        Increase Inc = new Increase();
        Inc.Val = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3);
        Inc.Val = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3);
        Inc.Val = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3);
    }

    public class Increase
    {
        private int val;
        public int Val
        {
            get { return val; }
            set { val = ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3++; }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much once again!

Comment: 1: Use a method instead of a property. 2: Make the class `ValuesForTableLooping` static as well

Comment: A setter usually enablaes setting a new value **from the outside**. Increasing the value **within** the setter seems very odd. mAybe you should use a `IncreaseVal`-method instead. Furthermore a class should not contain a **verb**, but usually a **noun**. Having said this a class is some kind of **entitiy**, not a thing you can **do with an entity**.

Comment: I think this question can be solved by a small amount of research into what properties are, and how they are used. I think this is a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties

Comment: Hint: `Inc.Val = 0;` the 0 is put into a "magic" (well, it exists without being declared in your code) variable called `value` when it enters the `set { }` method.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've already used a method but I wanted to explore various ways to acquire my goal. I see now that get and set are unreliable. Regarding the naming, I apologize as this was a test script and for me to test a concept. Thank you for the reminder that I need to follow the naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is pretty strange and you seem to have a great misunderstanding on what properties are.

A property is nothing - as you noticed - as a get- and a set-method. So you could achieve the exact same with the following code:

```
public int get_Val() { return val; }
public void set_Val(int value) { val = ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3++; }
```

And here is the weird thing. **A setter expects a new value for your property, which is provided as `value`**. However you don´t use that value at all in your implementation. Instead you just increase `val` by one, which I would call a really strange design. You either want to set the new value from the outside with this:

```
public void set_Val(int value) { val = value; }
```

or in the property-notation:

```
public int Val { 
    get { return val; }
    set { val = value; }
}
```

which can be further simplified by using an auto-implemented property:

```
public int Val { get; set; }
```

Another - IMHO better - way is to omit the setter completely and create some `IncreaseVal`-method instead:

```
public void IncreaseVal() { ValuesForTableLooping.Table10_3++; }
```

Last but not least `Increase` is a very bad name for a class. It does not describe a *thing*, but something you *can do with a thing*.